# ¿como solucionar el error write() argument must be str, not bytes?

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy usando `filedialog` de tkinter para guardar un archivo excel, el cual previamente lo lleno con una base de datos importada de mysql, pero al guardar el archivo se genera el documento vacio y me arroja el error `write() argument must be str, not bytes`, ¿porqué sucede esto?

```
from Data_Base import conexion
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd
from tkinter import filedialog

class Exportar_Base_Datos:
    def __init__(self):
        self.crearexcel()

    def hoja1(self,lista_BD, wb):
        hoja = wb.create_sheet(title = "SGUIMIENTO RCC")
        hoja.append(('CASO', 'FECHA', 'MES', 'AÑO', 'CLIENTE', 'DENOMINACION', 'CIUDAD_SEDE', 'TERRITORIAL', 'ESTADO_RCC', 'OC', 'OC_FISICA', 'EM', 'ESTADO_SAP', 'GESTOR', 'COMENTARIO','SINTOMA', 'TECNICO', 'FECHA_INICIO_EJECUCION', 'FECHA_FINAL_EJECUCION', 'MANO_OBRA', 'MATERIAL', 'PARAFISCALES', 'COSTO_TOTAL', 'SUBTOTAL_SAP', 'IVA','TOTAL_IVA', 'COMISION_OTROS', 'UTILIDAD_BRUTA', 'PORCENTAJE_UB', 'RTE_FUENTE','RTE_IVA', 'RTE_ICA', 'PAGO_FINAL', 'UTILIDAD_NETA', 'PORCENTA_UN', 'FACTURA_VENTA', 'FECHA_FACTURA'))
        for caso in lista_BD:
            hoja.append((caso['CASO'], caso['FECHA'], caso['MES'], caso['AÑO'], caso['CLIENTE'], caso['DENOMINACION'], caso['CIUDAD_SEDE'], caso['TERRITORIAL'], caso['ESTADO_RCC'],caso['OC'],caso['OC_FISICA'],caso['GESTOR'],caso['COMENTARIO'],caso['SINTOMA'],caso['TECNICO'],caso['FECHA_INICIO_EJECUCION'],caso['MANO_OBRA'],caso['MATERIAL'],caso['PARAFISCALES'],caso['COSTO_TOTAL'],caso['SUBTOTAL_SAP'],caso['IVA'], caso['TOTAL_IVA'], caso['COMISION_OTROS'], caso['UTILIDAD_BRUTA'], caso['PORCENTAJE_UB'], caso['RTE_FUENTE'], caso['RTE_IVA'], caso['RTE_ICA'], caso['PAGO_FINAL'], caso['UTILIDAD_NETA'], caso['PORCENTA_UN'],caso['FACTURA_VENTA'],caso['FECHA_FACTURA']))
    def crearexcel(self):
        
        archivo = filedialog.asksaveasfile(defaultextension=".txt", filetypes=[("Archivos de texto", "*.txt"), ("Todos los archivos", "*.*"), ("Libro de Excel","*.xlsx")])
        if archivo:
            
            exportar = conexion()
            EXP = exportar.ExportarDBExcel()
            wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
            wb.remove(wb.active)
            self.hoja1(EXP,wb)

            wb.save(archivo)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay diferencia entre usar `filedialog.asksaveasfile` y `filedialog.asksaveasfilename`:

- `filedialog.asksaveasfile` devuelve el fichero abierto para escritura, lo que resulta ser un objeto `file`.
- `filedialog.asksaveasfilename` devuelve el nombre del fichero como una string (`str`) que es lo que necesitas realmente.

Cambia una función por la otra para que te funcione.